# Windows 7 on Athlon XP 2200+ 736 MB - feasible?

Tags: windows-7, amd-athlon

Would it be workable to put Windows 7 on an old AMD Athlon XP 2200+ (1.8 GHz) with 736 MB of RAM? Or would this be really slow?

What are the experiences with a comparable system? (I am not interested in Aero stuff, etc.)

Update: After reading the answers, I decided NOT to install Windows 7. I reinstalled Windows XP instead.

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: @davr: the pc has xp on it for 5 years, but is getting dead slow (no surprise, I've never encountered a system running XP for so long), so a reinstall of XP is necessary anyway. Was wondering if Win7 wouldn't be a good option if I had to the the reinstall anyway...

Comment: "Was wondering if Win7 wouldn't be a good option if I had to the the reinstall anyway". not on this system, it wouldn't. stick to XP or upgrade the system memory to 2 GB, RAM is cheap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seriously, It may just work - but I wouldn't.... (I don't think you can install with less than 1GB of memory - personally, I wouldn't use it with less than 2)

736MB of memory just isn't a lot, and by the time you disable enough services and features (such as Aero) in order to give more free RAM, there isn't much point in running Windows 7 for the sake of just running it.

I would personally just use it for XP and be happy.

If you still want to go ahead, try running the [Windows Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1B544E90-7659-4BD9-9E51-2497C146AF15&displaylang=en).

Comment: "I don't think you can install with less than 1GB of memory" no problem to install Windows 7 on a system with only 512 MB.

Comment: Must of just been Vista then - I will retest a bit later - just remember a warning stating that the machine does not have enough memory.

Comment: not sure bout Vista's requirement now, XP won't install on 64 MB or less, which can be circumvented, e.g. via nLite ("disable minimum memory requirement")

Comment: +1 for suggesting the Update Advisor (which I didn't see at first).

Comment: just testing with a 32-bit Ultimate DVD in VBox, Windows starts fine with 256 MB, no dice with any lower settings though :)

Comment: "Starts with" is not the same as workable and usable... And, just tested in a VM, 512MB is the smallest size setup allows - http://i49.tinypic.com/jqg5zr.jpg

Comment: you can install if it doesn't meet the requirement. All windows installer will do is just give you a warning

Answer (score 2):

It will work, I have the same CPU in my laptop and ONLY 512 MB of RAM. I installed Windows 7 Ultimate, and it runs just fine for the Internet but as expected, it is slow for anything else.

Comment: What do you mean by anything else? In my case, anything else would be Word, Excel and Picasa. I think that is about it.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be a problem, *[Running Windows 7 on a Dinosaur](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/06/running-windows-7-on-a-dinosaur/)* proves that Windows 7 can run perfectly even on a 128 MB RAM with a Pentium II CPU.

I personally have an AMD Athlon 3000+ with 1.5 GB RAM. It runs even faster than my Intel Core 2 Dual T5300 at 1.73 GHz with 2.5 GB RAM.

Answer (score 1):

It would work all right, but even if you tweak the living daylights out of it (e.g. with [vLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLite_and_vLite)), it won't be as fast as Windows XP.

Is it feasible to buy a US$100 OS for such an old clunker? That's your call :)